# How to implement MyMethod() with Format("blah {0}", someValue) signature like string.format

Tags: c#, .net, string, arguments, string-formatting

String.Format and StringBuilder (via the AppendFormat method) allow callers to pump values into a string they have prepared, e.g:

```
string temp = string.Format("Item {0} of {1}, Record Id: {2} started...",
  itemCounter.ToString(),
  totalItemsToProcess.ToString(),
  myRecord.RecordId);
MyMethod(temp);
```

But rather than build a string and pass that into "MyMethod()" I'd rather have an overload that people called like this:

```
MyMethod("Item {0} of {1}, Record Id: {2} started...",
  itemCounter.ToString(),
  totalItemsToProcess.ToString(),
  myRecord.RecordId);
```

How would you implement that?
Is there something I can leverage or do I have to write a bunch of custom code?

Comment: Why you need MyMethod? I think string.format is more clear...

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel ?

Comment: #ArsenMkrt, MyMethod() is purely pseudo code.  I need to provide a method that accepts what is basically a string but a lot of the time there will be a variety of information to pump into it.  Allowing callers to use a string.format type overload makes usage easier and the rest of the code cleaner.

Comment: #V4Vendetta, for ease of use and to keep code cleaner.  BTW, I would see it as not too dissimilar to the AppendFormat() method on StringBuilder - which I'm guessing (with the greatest respect) you wouldn't call reinvention?

Comment: Interesting observation: in the question code I never said MyMethod() returned anything - but all code examples have MyMethod returninga a string.  Not a critism - just interesting :)

Comment: Great link with incredible tips & tricks in the comments section: http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's pretty trivial, but there are less trivial uses of params:

```
static string MyMethod( string format, params object[] paramList )
{
    return string.Format(format, paramList);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.  Params is it; my thanks to the others who provided links :)

Answer (score 3):

How about params?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx

Comment: Ah - spot on.  I knew there was an easy way.

Answer (score 2):

Look into [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx)

Comment: Sorry RedDeckWins - CharithJ bet you by 2 mins.

Comment: I answered 44 minutes ago, which means my answer was before a 38 or 42 minute ago answer...  if you hover over the "x minutes ago" you can see the time it was posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method and use String.Format inside, probably something like this:

```
private void MyMethod(string separator, params string[] strings)
{
      string concatenatedString = String.Format(separator, strings);

      //More processing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don's see the reason why you want to write your method in this case, but here how you can do that

```
public string MyMethod(string s, params object[] args)
{
     return string.Format(s,args);
}
```